# Is their a free .NET Decompiler that integrates with the Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, decompiling

Their has been a bit of a renaissance of .NET decompiler development since RedGate announced they will [stop producing the free version of RedGate Reflector](http://www.justaprogrammer.net/2011/02/02/redgate-reflector-7-news-roundup/). One opensource decompiler, [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), allows you to do step through debugging of a compiled assembly. I was using this to debug some assemblies I lack the source code for. However, its crashes too often for the level of nested debugging I need to do.

Ideally, I'd prefer something that integrates with Visual Studio 2010, or 2008, but I'll settle for anything stable. Free is preferable.

Comment: You can have free, you can have stable.  You can't have both.  Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: @Hans Passant, of course that you can have both: suffice to write one yourself. But totally agree with you about the off-topic nature of the question. @OP: if a tool is making me productive and save me time I would consider buying at. Wasted time costs much more than the 30 bucks you would spend.

Comment: Hmm, that would be neither free nor stable unless his time is free.  I don't think he's shopping for that.

Comment: I swear everytime I end up on a good SO question its marked off topic. Really getting tired of all the moderator nazis. >:(

Comment: @MikeOBrien Well [Jeff specifically blogged about shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) so I can't be mad.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look at dotPeek by JetBrains http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Does it include a debugger or support the VS debugger? If yes, why don't they mention in on the page you linked? A debugger in the decompiler is a really big feature IMO, so one would advertise that.

Comment: Debugging support is in the feature list http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/DOTP-176 (As you can see, this product is in the Early Access Program, so we can vote and wait)

Comment: Is there any decompiler that can decompile linq statements to what was actually written in code from dll?

Answer (score 0):

I've used dotPeek, my opinion is that it is NOT [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)

This may change though, since it is still an early access release.

If free is not a must, i would go for Reflector, which stays as #1 in my book - easy to use, integrates with VS.